# SQL Server : tick-by-tick data to OHLC

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help with a SQL query to convert tick-by-tick data to OHLC (Open\High\Low\Close) one in 1 minute intervals? I was able to get High and Low data, but having difficulties with Open and Close.

My sample data looks like this:

```
  idc   ServerDateTime          iDateTime   sSymbol cAsk    cBid    Spread
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2539581 2017-11-13 00:14:56.357 1510539296  EURUSD  1.16473 1.16460 0.00013
2539582 2017-11-13 00:14:56.373 1510539296  EURUSD  1.16475 1.16461 0.00014
2539583 2017-11-13 00:14:56.423 1510539296  EURUSD  1.16476 1.16462 0.00014
2539584 2017-11-13 00:14:56.520 1510539296  EURUSD  1.16477 1.16463 0.00014
2539585 2017-11-13 00:14:56.643 1510539296  EURUSD  1.16478 1.16463 0.00015
2539586 2017-11-13 00:14:58.207 1510539298  EURUSD  1.16478 1.16464 0.00014
2539587 2017-11-13 00:14:59.477 1510539299  EURUSD  1.16477 1.16464 0.00013
2539588 2017-11-13 00:15:00.337 1510539300  EURUSD  1.16477 1.16463 0.00014
2539589 2017-11-13 00:15:00.747 1510539300  EURUSD  1.16478 1.16463 0.00015
2539590 2017-11-13 00:15:00.873 1510539300  EURUSD  1.16477 1.16463 0.00014
2539591 2017-11-13 00:15:01.510 1510539301  EURUSD  1.16477 1.16464 0.00013
```

There are some similar question with answers, but those are for python and MySQL.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? I can see why you are having problems with open and close since those are derived from last trade price, which is missing from your data.

Comment: version is SQL Server 2017. above I've given new sample from my data. my data actually has more than 2 mln. rows.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution i found in this link. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61772/new

```
select  min(ServerDateTime) as DateTime
,       max(cBid) as Highest
,       min(cBid) as Lowest
,       min(case when rn_asc = 1 then [cBid] end) as first
,       min(case when rn_desc = 1 then [cBid] end) as Last
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by cast(cast(ServerDateTime as float) * 60 * 24 as int)
                    order by ServerDateTime) as rn_asc
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by cast(cast(ServerDateTime as float) * 60 * 24 as int)
                    order by ServerDateTime desc) as rn_desc
        ,       *
        from    dbo.MT4TICK
        ) as SubQueryAlias

group by
        cast(cast(ServerDateTime as float) * 60 * 24 as int)
order by DateTime
```